# how to exit a sensitivity process upon a condition being met

Tags: process, vhdl, conditional-statements

I have code that checks for a reset or a clock and if there is a clock it does some operations on 'buff'. I want to make it so that once 'buff' is equal to 'key', it will exit the process. How can I accomplish this?

```
PROCESS (clock, reset)
        BEGIN
            IF(reset = '1') THEN
                buff <= (others => '0'); -- set buffer to 0
                op <= (others => '0');   -- set output to 0
            ELSIF(clock'EVENT AND clock = '1') THEN
                op <= ip;  --output displays what was inputted
                buff(31 downto 8) <= buff (23 downto 0); --shift least significant 24 bits
                buff(7 downto 0) <= ip; --set empty 8 bits to input
                IF (buff = key) THEN
                    success <= '1';  --once buff = key, output a green light
                ELSE 
                    success <= '0';
                END IF;
            END IF;
    END PROCESS;
```

Comment: Assuming key has the same dimensionality as buff, inside the elsif with the clock condition an if statement providing a condition for execution of the assignment statements that requires buff /= key. (The comparison provides an enable to the registers).